# How to auto Logout when jwt token expired react

Tags: reactjs

I have 5 pages and had stored JWT token in local storage, in which screen should I write code for auto logout and what will be the Code in react

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
    <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />

    <ProtectedRoutes  exact path='/' component={Home}  />
    <ProtectedRoutes  exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
    <ProtectedRoutes  exact path='/about' component={About} />
    <ProtectedRoutes  exact path='/accounts' component={Accounts} />
    <ProtectedRoutes   component={Signin} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Signin Page

```
export default function Signin() { 

const submitData = async (data)=>{ 
        const apiData= await postSigninData(data)
         localStorage.setItem('token', apiData.data)
     }
  
    return (
        <Box>
           <h1> Signin Page</h1>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be page specific. If you don't have an option for refresh token then when you call any protected api with expired token you are supposed to get a failed response for expired token. Then you need can write your logout logic there. If you can validate your token before sending to any api , you can return a status and act on that.

So the idea is not page specific. If you have redux or context api setup , your failed API can return some value that will set a state in the store or global state. In your App component or any smart component you can watch for that and logout.